# multiple statements else if not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to replace a volume image when the player's volume level changes,
but with this code, the second `else if` does not work,
and the 3° image (VOL-1.png) does not appears...

All the other images (VOL-off, VOL-2, VOL-on) appear properly...

```
var myVideo1 = document.getElementById('myVideo1');
var bttnMuteUnmute = document.getElementById("bottoncinoMuteUnmute_myVideo1");

myVideo1.addEventListener("volumechange", function () {
    if (myVideo1.muted || myVideo1.volume <= 0.009) {
        bttnMuteUnmute.style.backgroundImage = "url(buttons-VOL-off.png)";
    } else if (myVideo1.volume <= 0.65) {
        bttnMuteUnmute.style.backgroundImage = "url(buttons-VOL-2.png)";
    } else if (myVideo1.volume <= 0.4) {
        bttnMuteUnmute.style.backgroundImage = "url(buttons-VOL-1.png)";
    } else {
        bttnMuteUnmute.style.backgroundImage = "url(buttons-VOL-on.png)";
    }
}, false);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: remembering that the if statements take place sequentially, ask your self which if statement is going to fire if the value is .2

Comment: else if should generally have 2 limits, upper and lower. In your if condition you just have upper limit. Anything less that 0.009 will will be true there and wont give control to other elseif statements. Make a upper limit and lower limit condition. OR change the order of the statements in which they execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any number which is lesser than `0.4` will also be lesser than `0.65`. So, when the number is lesser than `0.4`, it compares against `<= 0.65`, it is Truthy, so displays `VOL-2` picture.

So, you just have to change the order of the conditions, like this

```
...
} else if (myVideo1.volume <= 0.4) {
bttnMuteUnmute.style.backgroundImage = "url(buttons-VOL-1.png)";
} else if (myVideo1.volume <= 0.65) {
bttnMuteUnmute.style.backgroundImage = "url(buttons-VOL-2.png)";
} else {
...
```

Comment: im waiting 10 min! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since if-else statements are evaluated in order, it gets stuck in VOL-2 because any option for VOL-1 also meets VOL-2.  If you were to switch the order of VOL-1 and VOL-2, it should work.